# How can I use the enum tcp mib definitions in a kprobe program?

Tags: tcp, mib, kprobe, bcc-bpf

Here, I tried to write a program(kprobe) to include the enum tcp mib like @tcp_states in the book BPF Performance Tools bpftrace. The enum tcp mib is in '/include/uapi/linux/snmp.h':

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bpftrace

#include <net/net_namespace.h>
#include <net/netns/mib.h>
#include <net/snmp.h>
#include <uapi/linux/snmp.h>

#define TCP_MIB_MAX              __TCP_MIB_MAX

kprobe:sk_alloc
{
        $net = (struct net *)arg0;
        $mi = (struct netns_mib *)$net->mib;
        $ib = (struct tcp_mib *)$mi;
        
        @mib[1] = "TCP_MIB_NUM";
        @mib[2] = "TCP_MIB_RTOALGORITHM";
        @mib[3] = "TCP_MIB_RTOMIN";
        @mib[4] = "TCP_MIB_RTOMAX;
        @mib[5] = "TCP_MIB_MAXCONN";        
        @mib[6] = "TCP_MIB_ACTIVEOPENS";
        @mib[7] = "TCP_MIB_PASSIVEOPENS";
        @mib[8] = "TCP_MIB_ATTEMPTFAILS";
        @mib[9] = "TCP_MIB_ESTABRESETS";
        @mib[10] = "TCP_MIB_CURRESTAB";
        @mib[11] = "TCP_MIB_INSEGS";
        @mib[12] = "TCP_MIB_OUTSEGS";
        @mib[13] = "TCP_MIB_RETRANSSEGS";
        @mib[14] = "TCP_MIB_INERRS";
        @mib[15] = "TCP_MIB_OUTRSTS";
        @mib[16] = "TCP_MIB_CSUMERRORS";

        printf("-------------------------------\n");
        time();
        printf("sk_alloc: %s pid: %d\n", comm, pid);
        printf("\n");
        printf("$ib: %u\n", $ib->miss[6]);

        $mib_s = $ib->mibs[TCP_MIB_MAX];
        $mib_str = @mib[$mib_s];

        printf("TCP mib is: %s\n", $mib_str);

        clear(@mib);
}
```

And when I tried to run it the output was:

```
the index 94779518808448 is out of bounds for array of size 16
```

Then I tried to instead of TCP_MIB_MAX, to put specific array positions e.g 5, (I modify the above code):

```
$mib_s = $ib->mibs[5];
```

And when I tried to run it, the output was:

```
...

-----------------------------
21:40:15
sk_alloc: systemd-logind pid: 920

$ib: 1516359680
TCP mib is:

-----------------------------
21:40:15
sk_alloc: systemd-logind pid: 920

$ib: 1516359680
TCP mib is:

...
```

Why does not show TCP mib? and shows nothing in the output?
How can I use the array properly to show @mib?

Answer (score 0):

`TCP_MIB_MAX` and `__TCP_MIB_MAX` are equal to 16, which is equal to the size of the `struct tcp_mib` in the kernel:

```c
enum
{
    TCP_MIB_NUM = 0,
    TCP_MIB_RTOALGORITHM,           /* RtoAlgorithm */
    TCP_MIB_RTOMIN,             /* RtoMin */
    TCP_MIB_RTOMAX,             /* RtoMax */
    TCP_MIB_MAXCONN,            /* MaxConn */
    TCP_MIB_ACTIVEOPENS,            /* ActiveOpens */
    TCP_MIB_PASSIVEOPENS,           /* PassiveOpens */
    TCP_MIB_ATTEMPTFAILS,           /* AttemptFails */
    TCP_MIB_ESTABRESETS,            /* EstabResets */
    TCP_MIB_CURRESTAB,          /* CurrEstab */
    TCP_MIB_INSEGS,             /* InSegs */
    TCP_MIB_OUTSEGS,            /* OutSegs */
    TCP_MIB_RETRANSSEGS,            /* RetransSegs */
    TCP_MIB_INERRS,             /* InErrs */
    TCP_MIB_OUTRSTS,            /* OutRsts */
    TCP_MIB_CSUMERRORS,         /* InCsumErrors */   // == 15
    __TCP_MIB_MAX                                    // == 16
};
```

and

```c
#define TCP_MIB_MAX __TCP_MIB_MAX
struct tcp_mib {
    unsigned long   mibs[TCP_MIB_MAX];
};
```

(include/uapi/linux/snmp.h and include/net/snmp.h)

But because arrays are indexed from 0, you can go only up to `TCP_MIB_MAX - 1` when indexing `$ib->mibs`. This is why you get a complaint about the out-of-bound index.

Then when you select a smaller index, you can access to the array item as expected. But I'm not sure what you are trying to do with:

```sh
        $mib_s = $ib->mibs[5];
        $mib_str = @mib[$mib_s];
```

To me it looks like you are reading the value from the MIB (`$ib->mibs[TCP_MIB_ACTIVEOPENS]`), which may supply any value, possibly big, and likely null (I suspect this is the case here). Then you use that value as... an index in `@mib`? So if the counter is at 10k, you try to take the 10,000th cell of a 16-sized array? I suppose in your case the value is 0, so you are doing `$mib_str = @mib[0]`, which is likely an empty string because you never set a value for `@mib[0]`.

To fix all of this I would start by using the correct indices (from 0 to 15) for the `@mib` array, to avoid any confusion. Then you probably need to rethink what you are trying to print exactly, but I'm not sure that the two lines above is what you want.